# In Mac OSX Lion, how does one replace multiple spaces with a single space using sed?

Tags: macos, sed, osx-lion

friends, colleagues, glib claimers-to-know, and esteemed fellow victims of The Most Humiliating of Careers,

I am suffering from that distinctive fatigue one gets when trying to do simple UNIXy things in Max OSX.  Can someone tell me how to use sed (not awk, not perl, not anything but sed) to take file.txt containing this:

```
Oh         my I         have Mac                 fatigue
```

and make it look like this:

```
Oh my I have Mac fatigue
```

Thank you very much if you actually do this on in Mac OSX Lion. (edit: not Mountain Lion, either, a different OS). I just spent a long time Googling folks who answer for linux or UNIX in general, it's not much help sadly.

I tried a number of things from the blissful, long-forgotten days of standard pattern matching, when one could rattle off UNIXy commands and lo! they would behave:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/ */ /g'        - O h m y I h a v e M a c f a t i g u e
cat file.txt | sed 's/ \+/ /g'       - no effect
cat file.txt | sed 's/\s\+/ /g'      - no effect
cat file.txt | sed -E -e 's/ */ /g'  - O h m y I h a v e M a c f a t i g u e
```

Telling me to use sed on a linux machine will make me smile, but it won't get an upvote :)
Thanks in advance.  Not sure what I'd do without StackOverflow.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth checking for tabs also?

Comment: I did that, thank you.  The file I am really trying to process has only spaces, no tabs.  Thanks, though, for the thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works (tested on stock OS X 10.8.3):

```
 cat file.txt | sed -e "s/  */ /g"
```

(note that there are **two** spaces before the asterisk)

or to get rid of the [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat):

```
 sed -e "s/  */ /g" < file.txt
```

Comment: Both of those return single spaces uniformly between all letters in Lion.  I have Mac OSX 10.7.5 Lion, not Mountain Lion.  Thanks for the fast answer, but sorry, not correct for my OS.

Comment: Hello out there, up-votes.  Are you saying this works on your install of Lion? 10.7? Or are you up-voting the answer for Mountain Lion, 10.8?  Thanks.

Comment: Read the UUOC link. LOL thanks.  However, it ignores the way this sometimes occurs, where I was in fact concatenating files and then backed up partway to pipe the sed when I realized that some of the files being pushed together had multiple spaces between columns.  Laziness of typist on the command line is my only defense. :) great link

Comment: @noogrub: this should work in any version of OS X (and any other version of sed, for that matter). Note that there are two spaces before the asterisk in the search pattern; if you use only one space, you'll get to results you describe.

Comment: You could also use `sed -e 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'`, or `sed -Ee 's/ +/ /g'` (the `-E` switches to extended regex format, which allows the `+` operator).

Comment: Mr Davisson, Thank you very much, that is exactly correct for me, all of those work fine.  My apologies to Paul R for my initial assessment. Upvoting. Happy sedding everyone, thank you all.